# R how to examine kmeans model for use

Tags: r, classification, k-means

I am trying to figure out how to plot the kmeans data for use.

I created the kmeans model

```
model<-kmeans(euFlat,12)
```

I would like to apply this model back to my original data then create a chart by the classifiers 1-12 so I can see what the OHLC chart patterns look like that it was able to classify.

Currently I have flattened data

```
                    Open   High     Low   Close Volume
2008-06-25 18:00:00    0 0.0017  0.0000  0.0015      0
2008-06-25 22:00:00    0 0.0102 -0.0045  0.0080      0
2008-06-26 02:00:00    0 0.0014 -0.0002  0.0000      0
2008-06-26 06:00:00    0 0.0005 -0.0003  0.0003      0
2008-06-26 10:00:00    0 0.0016 -0.0025  0.0010      0
2008-06-26 14:00:00    0 0.0010 -0.0011 -0.0007      0
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to apply the kmeans back to the data to separate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classification vector is located in `model$cluster`. To put it back in the dataframe, you can use this:

```
cbind(euFlat, model$cluster)
```

Comment: Thanks dobyou know how I could classify a new point with the existtin model?

Comment: cl_predict() will predict new data from kmeans.